# Git: server certificate verification failed using Bitbucket Server

Tags: ssl, tomcat, certificate, git, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket server running onprem with a certificate.
I added it to the keystore ussing the follwing commands

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in myurl.com.cer -inkey myurl.com.key -out myurl.com.p12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myurl.com.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore bitbucket.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

It looks like this if i view the server in Chrome (which looks good):

[image]

When i try clone a Repository from the Server i get the Following Error

```
root@BS01:~# git clone https://source.server.com/scm/p/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
```

> fatal: unable to access 'https://source.server.com/scm/p/project.git':
>   server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

On windows the error looks a bit different:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://source.server.com/scm/p/project.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

When i Google for this error a lot of soltions suggest that i have to use a CA Certificate istead of a selfsigned one (Maybe I got the concept wrong but i thought the Certificate is a CA Certificate) or disable sslVerificaction entirely (which is not acceptable)
What problem does git have with the certificate and how to fix that?

Comment: Is the `Issued to:` field actually blank? Or did you do edit it for privacy?

Comment: @Ryan it is filled, just "erased".

Answer (score 0):

Acually the certificate is only fine on my Computer, Mobile Devices did not trust it aswell - if I concatenate the whole trust chain into one .pem file looking like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
KEY FROM domain.key
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
domain.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
Intermediate.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
Root.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And add this one to the jks it works as expected.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.pem \
    -out server.p12 -name  tomcat
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.p12 \
    -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore bitbucket.jks -deststoretype JKS
```